# Firefox Radio Button Weirdness

Tags: firefox, radio-button

I have a form with a lot of groups of radios.  Each radio has a unique id and has the same name as the others in its group.  The page validates as XHTML transitional.

Tested in IE6 & 7, Opera, Safari, and Chrome it works exactly as you would think it would from either mouse or keyboard input.

In FireFox it goes crazy.  A single click on any radio in a group sets the first radio in the group checked.  A double click on a radio usually selects it.  Anyone seen this before?

Sample group looks like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="upAndDown_1" id="upAndDown_11" value="Y"  /> Y <br />
<input type="radio" name="upAndDown_1" id="upAndDown_12" value="N"  checked="checked" /> N<br />
<input type="radio" name="upAndDown_1" id="upAndDown_13" value="NA"  /> NA
```

The phonmomenon can be tested here:  http://www.nolaflash.com/stackoverflow/firefox_and_radios.html

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doh!  My designer had a single  tag wrapping each group of radios.  Eliminating the label tag fixes FireFox's weirdness.

Comment: Yes, an input inside a label is considered as associating the label with the input, as if a `for="..."` had been used to associate them. This is part of the HTML standard, though not supported by IE.

Comment: The behavior happens when you have the same id for the radios if you assign the same name and different id's you wont have this effect.

Answer (score 5):

It's indeed the surrounding `<label>` tag that causes the Firefox issue (although it is valid html).
This should do the trick:

```
<input type="radio" name="upAndDown_2" id="upAndDown_21" value="Y"/><label for="upAndDown_21">Y</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="upAndDown_2" id="upAndDown_22" value="N"/><label for="upAndDown_22">N</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="upAndDown_2" id="upAndDown_23" value="NA" checked="checked"/><label for="upAndDown_22">NA</label>
```