# asp.net radiobutton list - in firefox only - one of the buttons is disabled

Tags: asp.net, firefox, radiobuttonlist

So I added a simple RadioButtonList list with two items on my asp.net form. However, I can't select the "flat" ListItem. It appears greyed out, but in **firefox only**. It works fine in Chrome and IE. In FF the only way I could get the "Flat" Item to be selected is if I set the Selected="True". However, if I then selected the "Standard" item I could not go back and reselect the "Flat" item. Any ideas? Environment is C# ASP.Net 4/VS 2010

```
<fieldset>
 <label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBListSpecs" runat="server" TabIndex="6" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
              <asp:ListItem Value="standard" Selected="True" Enabled="True">Standard</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="flat" Selected="False" Enabled="True">Flat (Less than 16 mm)</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
 </label>
```

Comment: try removing the label tag.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619336/firefox-radio-button-weirdness

Comment: Yes, I was playing around with it and removing the label tag does the trick, though taking away the label seems to break the TabIndex.

Comment: Looks like you can leave the label, if you give them separate id's from some of the comments on that thread, if that works you can keep the TabIndex functionality

Comment: "id" is not a valid attribute for an <asp:ListItem>. Anyway it not that big of a deal in this case.